# Mod rewrite rule for cached pages

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am caching pages in my (Rails) application based on subdomain.  The pages for certain actions are cached to /public/cache/(subdomain)/.  The application is running under Apache with Phusion Passenger.   The caching is working fine.  The problem is that Apache is not picking up the cached pages and bypassing Rails like it should be.  My rewrite rules are wrong and I need help fixing them.

I have used, as one example of many, the suggestion located at: https://github.com/yeah/page_cache_fu#readme, which is as follows:

```
RewriteMap uri_escape int:escape
<Directory /var/www/example.com/current/public>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET [NC]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING}.html -f
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ cache/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1${uri_escape:%{QUERY_STRING}}.html [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET [NC]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{HTTP_HOST}/index.html -f
  RewriteRule ^$ cache/%{HTTP_HOST}/index.html
```

The problem with this is it seems to be expecting the directory to be the full http host (i.e. it's looking in cache/subdomain.example.com rather than just cache/subdomain).

Edit:  Even when I change the Rails app to cache to cache/subdomain.example.com Apache still does not use them so it seems that there is more wrong than just the subdomain aspect.

Could someone please help me come up with the correct rule?

Edit(2):

I have simplified my rewrite to the following (just to try to get to a working starting point):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond ^stats$ cache/%1/stats.html [L]
```

I would think this would cause http://abc.example.com/stats to be rewritten to http://abc.example.com/cache/abc/stats.html

It is not.  I also added a RewriteLog entry and what I see there makes me think it is trying to redirect to http://abc.example.com/var/www/example.com/current/public/cache/abc/stats.html.  This is further confirmed by that if I add an 'R' option along with the 'L' I see in my browser http://abc.example.com/var/www/....etc.  I.e. it seems to be appending the full document root instead of just the public facing part.

Of course the result of the above is that I get a 404 error returned to the browser.

Can you see what is still wrong with my rule?

Edit:  It's actually a bug.

http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=563

Comment: Can you provide an example of the redirect you're trying to effect here. I.e. "When I navigate to `URL`, I'd like to be redirected to `OtherURL`". Please be exact. Thanks.

Comment: Agent, these are the two main instances I would like to use it in:  When I navigate to:  http://abc.example.com, I want to be redirected to http://abc.example.com/cache/abc/index.html; and when I navigate to http://abc.example.com/stats, I want to be redirected to http://abc.example.com/cache/abc/stats.html.  In both cases only when the cached file exists.  And in both cases I would prefer that the url that shows up in the browser not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this *looks* like it should work, but it doesn't. I've done a lot of testing with this, and it seems like the problem is the `^([^.]+)$` in the RewriteRule. Now, I did Google this, and it seems like it's a common enough pattern, so I don't understand what the issue could be. I just know that when I use *that pattern* in a RewriteRule, the rule fails. If I change it to `^([^.]+)`, it seems to work.

Hopefully someone with more experience with mod_rewrite can come along and explain to *us* what the problem with that pattern might be.

Edit: I just realized the problem with `^([^.]+)$`:

Since you're building a cache, then the "normal" file will exist in its usual place. The implication of this is that if you ask the server for `/file` then, depending on your configuration, it will say "hey, `file` doesn't exist, so let's try the default extension of `.html`!" and so it goes off and finds `file.html`. Now when you get to the RewriteRule, the `^([^.]+)$` regex will be matched against `file.html` NOT `file`.

The `^([^.]+)$` says "the start of the string, followed by as many non-period characters as you can grab, followed by the end of the string" which works fine against `file` because it contains no periods. It fails against `file.html` because `^[^.]+` will match against `file`, but where the regex then expects to find the end of the string (i.e. `$`), it instead finds `.html` and fails.

The reason `^(.*)$` works is that it's guaranteed that only `.*` will be the whole of the string, since `.*` matches "as many of any character" so there is no character that can possibly exist between the `(.*)` and `$` portions of the regex. That's not the case with `[^.]+`.

---

In order to extract the subdomain, you're going to need to backreference a RewriteCond. Basically, if you capture a reference (i.e. encapsulate something inside parens) in a RewriteCond, those references are available to a RewriteRule which immediately follows it.

For example, if I wrote this:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example.com
```

Then the parentheses would capture the subdomain - note the `()` around `[^.]+`

If I were then to write a RewriteRule on the next line, the text captured above would become accessible as `%1`.

So your RewriteRule would look like this:

```
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+) cache/%1/$1${uri_escape:%{QUERY_STRING}}.html [L]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Agent, thanks for your time on this.  I'm not sure what your conclusion is, though.  Are you saying that if I just remove the $ sign it will work?  FWIW now that I think about it I think I may only need the second rewrite rule, because I will not be caching pages that have query parameters.  It seems to me that the solution does involve some form of "^([^.]+)" in order to parse out the subdomain (followed by a $1 in the rule to indicate that the file is in a directory with that name.  I'm just not sure how to translate that into a complete rule.

Comment: @Ken: I think you're confused. `^([^.]+)` isn't parsing the subdomain. RewriteRule acts against the requested file, not the full URI. In other words, when you request `http://sub.example.com/file.html`, RewriteRule only matches the pattern against `file.html`.

Comment: Ok, then the question remains how do I get the subdomain and put it in the rewrite?  It seems I would need something like ^$ cache/%{HTTP_SUBDOMAIN}/index.html (for the case where '/' is requested), but I presume there is no such variable as HTTP_SUBDOMAIN

Comment: @Ken: I forgot about that part. I've added it to the end of my answer. Basically, you pass it as a reference from a `RewriteCond` into your `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Agent, based on your input and further reading I have tried something even simpler but it still isn't working.  Please see Edit(2) in my question.  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @Ken: You need to add a leading slash to your RewriteRule. i.e. use `/cache/%1/stats.html` instead of `cache/%1/stats.html`

Comment: Agent, thanks--we are getting somewhere.  This works, but only with the R there.  It does a 302 so the browser shows the rewritten url to the user.  This isn't the end of the world, but it's not ideal.  If I remove the R, the request is ending up getting to my Rails app which causes an error since there is no route for that url.  I am marking the answer as accepted but if you can help me clean up the url I would appreciate it.  Maybe it's a Rails question but I don't think so because the request should never hit Rails if it's using the cache.

Comment: @Ken: You really shouldn't need the `[R]` there at all. Do you have other RewriteRules in your `.htaccess` file that might be messing with it?

Comment: There is no .htaccess file.  The rewrite rules are placed in a Directory element in a virtual host file in the sites-available directory.  At this time the rule I put in my last edit is the only rule.

Comment: @Ken: As a general rule, `<Directory>` blocks work the same as `.htaccess` files. If you set rules up outside of one of those two, you could run into issues, but for all intents and purposes `<Directory>` and `.htaccess` files work the same way.

Comment: Agent--I know.  I was just answering your question.  So do you know why it won't work without doing a 302 redirect?

Comment: @Ken: No idea. Like I said it should work without a 302. You could try doing an explicit 301 - `[R=301]` - and seeing if that works, but honestly, the code should work fine without it. Are you sure you don't have any other rules which might be interfering?

Comment: @Ken: You could turn on the log and see what it has to say on the matter.